# Tag list runs over posting duration

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

In the job search view, a posting has a list of tags associated with it. If that list is long enough (or the text in those tags is long enough) it overruns the posting duration:

[image: job search view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great catch. Typically most jobs can only add five tags, but sysadmin jobs can have up to six tags. One the sysadmin tag and then five for the job listing. Combining the use of all 6 tags plus with longer tags names, you've discovered a nice rare edge case.

I've added a width to the tags container to make sure this doesn't overlap with the time stamp.

[image: Trivago Job listing with 6 tags]

Thanks for reporting the issue!

Comment: I'd be remiss to not report it :) Thanks for the fast fix!